# Kernel upgrade to 4.4.0-103.126 fails and /boot is now too full to remove it

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and my upgrade to linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic fails because my /boot directly is almost full (188MB out of 200MB).

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic; however:
Package linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic is not configured yet.
```

dpkg shows that I only have the 2 most recent kernels installed (4.4.0-96-generic and 4.4.0-97-generic).

```
claude@shannon:~$ sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trigpend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                           Version                    Architecture                 Description
+++-==============================================-============================-    ============================-===================================================    ===============================================
un  linux-image                                    <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic                  4.4.0-103.126                amd64                        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
un  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic                   <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic                   4.4.0-81.104                 amd64                        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic                   4.4.0-83.106                 amd64                        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic                   4.4.0-96.119                 amd64                        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic                   4.4.0-97.120                 amd64                        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic             4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1          amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic             4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1          amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic            4.4.0-103.126                amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic             4.4.0-59.80                  amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic             4.4.0-62.83                  amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic             4.4.0-63.84                  amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic             4.4.0-64.85                  amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic             4.4.0-72.93                  amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic             4.4.0-77.98                  amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic             4.4.0-81.104                 amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic             4.4.0-83.106                 amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic             4.4.0-96.119                 amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic             4.4.0-97.120                 amd64                        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                            4.4.0.103.108                amd64                        Generic Linux kernel image
```

I thought about uninstalling one of them to make room for the new one, but uname -r shows 4.4.0.96-generic as the current kernel, not 4.4.0-97-generic. I'm not sure why the more recent kernel isn't being used, and I don't want to uninstall either one if I don't have to.

```
claude@shannon:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-96-generic
```

sudo apt-get autoremove fails because /boot is too full

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
(and so on)
```

How do I install the latest kernel and remove the old kernel packages?

Comment: Remove old initrds from /boot by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually `mount /dev/sdx /boot` (where x is the boot partition, assuming sata is used) and rm the unwanted images.

Keep in mind that the bootloader configuration has to be updated as well. (e.g. assuming grub is used `grub-mkconfig /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or editing it manually)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to fix it. It turns out the server didn't restart after the prior update to 4.4.0-97-generic, so it was still running 4.4.0-96-generic. I shut down all the services and rebooted, and it made 4.4.0.97-generic the kernel. Then, I ran

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and rebooted again. Now 4.4.0-103-generic is the kernel, and 4.4.0-97-generic is the old kernel.